# Running same keyword reset variable to none in robot framework

Tags: selenium, robotframework

When I run my keyword twice my variable get set to None even after adding a condition.

Here's my code

```
*** Variables ***
${num01}    1
${num01}    2

KOOK
    [Arguments]    ${check}=${NONE}
    ${num01}    set variable if    '${check}' == '${NONE}'
    ...    10
    run keyword if    '${check}' == '${NONE}'    log to console    HOOOO ${num01}
    run keyword if    '${check}' == '${NONE}'    set test variable    ${num01}

    ${num02}    set variable if    '${check}' != '${NONE}'
    ...    20
    run keyword if    '${check}' != '${NONE}'    log to console    HAAAA ${num02}
    run keyword if    '${check}' != '${NONE}'    log to console    HAAAA ${num01}
```

My keyword

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test
    KOOK
    KOOK    yes
```

Result

```
HOOOO 10

HAAAA 20
HAAAA None
```

I have a solution is to split my keyword but is anyone could bring me a solution to use the same keyword it would be very helpfull

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what exactly you want from this code, but the keyword **set variable if** needs two values, one is set when the condition is met and the other if the condition is not. Since the condition is not met when you call it the second time it gets set to none.
With this minor change, you should be able to see the difference.

```
KOOK
    [Arguments]    ${check}=${NONE}
    ${num01}    set variable if    '${check}' == '${NONE}'
    ...    10    20
```